# Is Recent Activity superfluous? What about the other user pages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, recent-activity, user-interface

I'm not saying there shouldn't be a *Recent Activity* page, but the way it's currently implemented feels a bit... out of place. It's currently separate from the user page (`/users/recent/481512342` vs. normal `/users/481512342?tab=recent`) and could be condensed into the user page, in my opinion.

The additional tabs that are on the *Recent Activity* page feels to me like they are mostly there for looking at historical data, because usually you go to the overview often enough not to miss anything important. They could be made accessible in some other way than tabs, because I think there's too many tabs on the user page already.

Speaking of the tabs on the user page, there are a lot of them, and some of them show little more than trivia (a detailed listing of all the up/down votes I've placed?) The *prefs* and *accounts* tabs belong in another section, because you do not need quick access to them, and they will also be growing in the future. A viable solution might be to change the *edit* link to something like *manage account* which in turn has *profile*, *prefs* and *linked accounts* tabs or something like that.

Those are all my thoughts. Discuss!

Comment: votes tab removed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Recent Activity page is a good way to follow todays changes to your rep and conversations, but more importantly, it is great if you have asked questions, as the answers (and links to them) and comments will be posted there.  I use that page more than I do my 'user' page.

However, you bring up a very good point.  Should thee two be consolidated?  I think so.  For one thing, finding the Recent Activity page is not intuitive, while there are multiple access methods to your user page (through the Users view or clicking on your username link wherever you see it on the page).  Also, when you get down to it, the two are really describing the same thing: you and your stats.

Just as you have custom views on your own user page as opposed to when you are looking at another user's page (votes and prefs, for example), the Recent Activity data could be rolled into a custom tab on your user page.  I would argue that it should be the default view of *my* user page, and not be available when looking at another user's page.

Comment: recent activity is supposed to be private (eg your RESPONSES -- is your email public to the world?), also, we don't want the user page to explode in size / tabs.

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the comment.  I get the public vs private, but what about the two private tabs on the User page now (votes & prefs)?  I also get the scaling issues with tabs.

Answer (score 4):

It's the only place that I can find links to the questions I've commented on. Often, I'll leave a comment on a question asking the OP for more info or what have you. I use my Recent page to find that comment again to check and see if the OP had responded.

Now, if there were a Comments section of the main page, that'd be fantastic, but I'm making due just fine with the current layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's weird to "hide" Recent Activity where it is. When I was a newbie I had no idea how to find my recent answers and comments. I was expecting a my.stackoverflow.com or another tab or something.

Comment: OT Nosredna, who is that in your profile pic?