# Where did the Votes Tab go?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, profile-page

My profile page used to have a votes tab that showed me what my latest X votes were. It is not there anymore. What happened to it? Why was it removed? I looked everywhere but couldn't find anyone talking about it. I use this often to go back to downvotes and see if they've been edited to fix a problem so I can then remove my downvote.

**Edit:** I made this a feature request to bring this functionality back.

Comment: I know it was there yesterday, is missing for me currently.

Comment: I also want to view all the posts that I voted up and voted down before as I want to keep track all the good posts for my future reference.

Comment: I would really want to see this implemented.

Comment: A weak workaround for __answers__ that you cast __down__ votes on is to skim through your profile's reputation tab looking for `-1`s.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Votes Tab is Back from vacation.

It took a long term vacation so it could come back, bigger, stronger and betterer.

We brought it back in a format very similar to the activity stream, clearly you can only see your votes. You can see deletions/undeletions/closures and reopens as well as up/down votes.

One slight open question is how to add a filter that allows you to see stuff that you downvoted in the past and now is no longer vote locked. For the time being you can trawl through your downvoted list.

And it is now full fledged. We can see different vote casts.

1. Upvotes
2. Downvotes
3. Delete Votes
4. Undelete Votes
5. Closure Votes
6. Reopen Votes

[image: Screenshot of the votes tab]

Answer (score 36):

+1

I wanted to follow up on a question I downvoted and now I can't find it anymore... I used this tab to this end.

**Please bring it back**

Answer (score 15):

I'll miss this tab... I use it quite a bit when investigating unusual voting patterns.

But I'd agree that it probably isn't very useful to your standard user.

Comment: Are there any plans to bring this back? If not, may I ask why?

Comment: @Chris it was removed over two years ago, before I worked for SE. I wasn't involved in the discussion re changing it, but ultimately I think I was wrong - for my purposes the existing UI worked fine. Is there something you need?

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be completely removed - visiting my votes URL [directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/658?tab=votes#sort-top) doesn't work either. However, it doesn't make much sense as to why, unless this is related to [this "bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/should-displayed-reputation-always-be-rounded-to-the-nearest-10) (which I couldn't verify) and has been taken temporarily offline until a hole is patched.