# What was I just looking at?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I can't find the thread I was just browsing.

I used to:

- look in threads recently upvoted.  I can't find that now
- look in favorites, sorted by most recent.  this sorts by most recent *activity*, not most recently "favorited"
- IF I commented the thread, use the **recent** tab.  Only works if you commented or answered the question though

How do you quickly find the thread you were just browsing if you didn't leave a comment or answer it?  Can we still access "recent votes"?  It was a useful thing!

**edit**

FWIW, the point of this question is to point out the upvote-to-bookmark feature is gone.  I liked it and I thought it was a great feature, though it might not have been intended to be used the way I used it.

Top voted answer has nothing to do with what I'm talking about here.

Comment: Now *this* is an existential question. +1 because I'm a Kierkegaard fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've cleared it up and are now talking about the Votes tab, well, sadly, it's... how should this be put...?

[It's... well it's gone. Passed away. No longer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go)

Answer (score 7):

Browser History?

Comment: I actually don't keep history.

Comment: Time to start :)

Comment: @bobobobobobobobo: Don't browse StackOverflow in porn mode.

Comment: Wow.  Its because it slows FF down!

Comment: And I thought you write him a Greasemonkey script...

Comment: @bobobobobobobobobo: http://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: @bobobobo: How slow could it possibly be? I use FF, *with history*, and I am not affected.

Comment: @Sampson:  You are.  Its incredibly slow.  Try turning it off.

Comment: @boboboobobobobobobobobo So you'd rather the sites managed your browser history for you? - Surely that slows it down for everyone else. In all honesty, the limiting factor on my browsing speed is my connection to the Internet, but I can't fix that without moving house. (Monopolies are bad)

Comment: @bobobobo - So in short the site needs to solve a problem for 1% of users that actually turn of browser history because they have the perception that it's faster without it? Wow. I learnt something new today.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Diago

Comment: @bobobobo: It's not "incredibly" slow. I am rather comfortable with how quickly FF functions. Why on Earth would I turn it off and join the ranks of those who can't find what page they visited yesterday? I prefer good speed + productivity over great speed - productivity anyday.

Comment: @bobobobo: I would like to think that Jonathan Sampson knows how fast or slow his browser experience is. Again: Search on these sites or Google. Surely, if the thread was that important, you remember a few details about it that would allow you to find it via Google or S[OFU]'s search?

Comment: Forget it all and just use Opera already.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. Please be stubborn as possible to everyone who trys to help you with your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Search. The back button on the browser. Undo Close Tab if needed (and the browser supports it). When push really comes to shove, Google: `site:stackoverflow.com +term +term`.

Upon reading the detailed comments, I have to ask: Is turning off history really that much of a performance boost in Firefox? I mean, I browse with history off -- but my Back button and Undo Close Tab (and their Back buttons) all still work, so I don't know if there are additional paranoia buttons I should be hitting. :) My browsing experience never seemed slower just because history was on ...

But it doesn't matter. Ultimately, adding a feature to track threads we've viewed seems difficult at best and a quagmire at worst. I view a lot of threads. I only care about a few. If I care about them, I mark them "favorite," or I upvote them, or I comment, or I post an answer. Sometimes a combination!

With the ability to search, assuming you remember even just a few key points from the post you are so interested in, you should be able to find it. If you can't find it using S[OFU]'s search, you can Google it -- most S[OFU] posts seem to get on Google faster than you'd believe.

It seems to me that adding a feature like this is catering to a *very* limited audience: Those who browse with history turned off, and forget all of the contents of the very important thread they were just viewing such that searching is not viable. I can't believe that's a very large audience.

Comment: On Chrome, I need to use +term +term site:stackoverflow.com, otherwise it decides I want to use the site's own search...

Comment: That's weird; then again I don't use Chrome ... I've always gone the other direction. Which is correct Google-fu?

Comment: Google-fu is fluid and doesn't matter how you strike, so long as you find what you're looking for on the first page.

Comment: I had recently had to reset my computer and all my history is gone...