# Making 'favorites' more usable

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

I still find **favorites** doesn't fill the need of finding the questions I've favorited in the last 2 days or so.

I find the 'recent' and 'newest' tabs really do almost the same thing - sort by "question with most recent activity" and "question order by date" respectively but I'd argue "newest" isn't useful except for the SO historians among us (wrt. getting answers, questions are mostly timeless, are they not?)

The 'recent' tab is great for seeing what of your favorite threads have new posts to them but to me this seems to be really noisy data and I can't gather much meaning from it.

I'm not sure if the information about **when** something was favorited is saved or not but I think a really helpful tab for me would be "by order of most recently **favorited**".  I used to use the [votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21337/what-was-i-just-looking-at) tab, but alas [that's gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go).

I'm saying it should be something like YouTube where the **most recent thing you favorited** is at the top of your favorites list, down to the very first thing you every favorited on the site at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Well sometime between then and now somebody did this.. ty Mr. Awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now have an "added" sort for favorites which does this.

Additionally, you will be notified via envelope / topbar when there are significant changes to your favorited questions.

Comment: Wasn't this added a long time ago? I recall using the "added" tab like 2 or 3 weeks ago

Comment: @earlz the sort is not new, but the favorites lighting up your envelope and having a tab in /recent is new