# What does "You have {n} favorite change(s)" mean?

Tags: support, bookmarks, faq-proposed

Apparently there was a new message/functionality introduced today. I gather it displays answers and comments on one's favored questions and displays this the same way as "You've new answers". Is this feature documented somewhere?

Comment: A documented new feature here? haha.

Comment: Where did you hear about this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28196/making-favorites-more-usable/51875#51875 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity

Comment: I was presented the same notification today but to me it looked like a favored question was deleted and hence removed from my favlist.

Comment: I tagged this as faq-proposed because I bet it will soon be a common question. Or maybe the answer to this should be merged to some notification based faq?

Comment: On an unrelated sidenote, for some reason I get the feeling that it was a bad idea to bookmark more than 500 questions.

Comment: I favourited the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/)... argh.

Comment: @ether lol that's awesome

Comment: @ether I created it, can you imagine the stuff I get :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Favorites now track changes -- so when you mark a question as a favorite, you're opting in to change notification on that question.

see:

[Show updates to favorite questions in recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity)

and all the questions in the Linked and Related column of that question.