# Tracking the questions you've recently viewed or visited

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, revisions-list, tracking

On your user profile page there are six (6) tabs; stats, activity, reputation, favorites, prefs and accounts.

I would like to see in a new tab, maybe named **50 latest viewed questions**, which would contain the 50 latest viewed questions.

This would help when I want to follow a question but don't want to bookmark it or add it to my favorites list.

Sometimes, or a few hours later, I can't even find it again. I think this would be good for when you're viewing questions at work and want to check it up at home but can't because it's not in the same browser history.

Comment: There is also your browser history...

Comment: Insightful reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21337/what-was-i-just-looking-at

Comment: i've found the "sort by" tabs invaluable for locating recent posts -- do a search for some related keyword, then sort by "newest" or "active" instead of "votes" or "relevance".  this won't help with the seen-but-failed-to-bookmark-or-favorite-it, but oh well...

Comment: This would be much like Google's search history, which I find very useful on occasions where I forgot to bookmark a link.

Comment: This is declined as per Nick's technical explanation in [Add a “recently viewed” tab in the user account page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315#116315).

Answer (score 4):

I think it'd be more appropriate under the `Activity` tab, with a new button called `Viewed`.

This would filter to a list of questions you've viewed in chronological order.  I don't think we need an infinite history there though, maybe 50 or 100 max.

Answer (score 3):

I came here to suggest this today, and have to +1/bump it.

Also, I'd suggest that a recently viewed questions could also live on the front page UI, above Recent Tags.