# How do we get list of questions we visited?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking the questions you’ve recently viewed or visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/tracking-the-questions-youve-recently-viewed-or-visited)

Is it possible to see the list of questions we visited on SO during the current session?

Comment: You mean like in your browser history?

Comment: yep but browser independent .. mean if we login to other pc it will be still available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in feature specifically for this. You can use a combination of:

1. Browser history
2. Activity list (where you left comments and answers)
3. Favorite questions