# Questions recently involved in

Tags: feature-request

**Related:**

- [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don't own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)
- [Tracking the questions you've recently viewed or visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/tracking-the-questions-youve-recently-viewed-or-visited)

**My suggestion (which is slightly different than the ones posted above):**

I would like a place where I could see questions I have recently been involved with. This would include:

- questions I have commented on (and questions on which I commented on an answer)
- questions I have posted an answer to
- maybe even questions I have voted on (and questions where I have voted on an answer)

Right now, it's a bit hard to keep track of all these questions, and I find myself leaving a comment on a question, that person responding and me forgetting about the question. And that is unwillingly rude.

This *place* that I speak of could be:

- on the profile page
- in the box that appears when clicking on the StackExchange logo
- in the box that appears when clicking on my user name (header)

This is the only thing that (currently) bugs me about the usability of the SE sites, but it bugs me bad.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the [Activity page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142212/felix?tab=activity)? You can even filter by accepts, **posts**, badges, **comments**, revisions, and reviews.

Comment: I guess it's just not organized they way I'd like it. If I write three comments on a question I don't want to see them all, I just want to see the question itself, once.