# Is it possible to add a Question-Visit History?

Tags: feature-request, questions, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking the questions you've recently viewed or visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/tracking-the-questions-youve-recently-viewed-or-visited)

I'm relatively new in this community and hope that I did not overlooked this kind of feature.
My Problem is the following:

I'm visiting Stack overflow from different devices (iphone, ipad, pc) and places (home, friend, work) and looking for nice questions.

Sometimes I found one on my ipad where I want to write an answer and not only reading them on the device. I really don't want to answer it on such a device like the ipad. Also because I often like to make an example in jsfiddle.

So I'm starting my computer and now there starts my problem: I had to enter the whole url instead of clicking on a list "last visited". I'm logged in on all devices so it would be cool to have a history with last visited questions.

I know that there is a favor function, but I do not want to favor everything only because I change devices. Then i had to favor it, write something, dislike it again.

To have a list with my last visited questions would also be also nice if I forgot to use this favor function in work and want to find the question again at home.

So is it possible to add some functionality?

I hope I described the reason why I want to have this in enough detail. And be sure I really want to have this feature!

Comment: @Arjan: yes i think he wants the same. Sorry! I was using the search function an tried some keywords, also i did look to everything which the system says "possible duplicate" but i did not find this one. Because of the date, of your link, i think this will never come :(

Comment: There's also the "favorite" star in the margin of the question, below the vote buttons. Your favorite questions are listed in your profile. I use it for this purpose frequently.