# Is there a way to quickly see the questions and answers I've voted on?

Tags: feature-request, voting, hyperlinks

I know that Stack Overflow, etc. keep track of which items I've voted on, as I can't duplicate my vote, etc.  But I don't see a way to directly access the items that I've voted on.

For example, I might have downvoted something and left a comment.  If the item was edited to correct my complaint, I would like to be able to remove that vote, but I also don't want to bookmark every vote I make.  It seems like the sites should present that information to me directly.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be a tab in the user profile that showed your recent voting history. [But it's gone now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go).

Comment: It also only showed the most recent activity.

Comment: I sure wish they'd bring that back.  It really helped me find posts that I'd looked at.

Comment: Changing from support to feature-request, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all your downvotes, they are listed (-1) on your reputation page.

Comment: This isn't completely true any more, as down votes on questions are now free.

Comment: As are downvotes on Community Wiki posts.