# Vote ups / downs where to find them?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to quickly see the questions and answers I've voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-see-the-questions-and-answers-ive-voted-on)
>   [There is no overview of recently cast downvotes any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91449/there-is-no-overview-of-recently-cast-downvotes-any-more)

Wondering if I missed this somewhere, but if I vote up a question or vote down a question I see the stats of up votes and down votes in my profile.  But is there any way to see the actual topics that I voted up or down?

For instance, recently I read a topic on stackoverflow about windows authentication problems and I upvoted it yesterday but I forgot to save / favorite the link.  I can't even remember how I found it, I eventually worked the google magic.

But I'd like to be able to easily go back to a topic I upvoted and see it..how can I do that?