# Determine number of votes on questions

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

I would like to know how many questions I have voted up and how many answers I have voted up ***separately***.  Is there some query I could run to figure that out?

I want a count of how many questions I have voted up.

And I want a count of how many answers I have voted up.

Comment: Where?  I see a combined score, but not separate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to quickly see the questions and answers I've voted on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23741/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-see-the-questions-and-answers-ive-voted-on)

Comment: @AʟE., nope, I'm trying to see a count, not a list.

Comment: I'd prefer not to run through a few hundred votes counting which ones go on questions and which on answers.

Comment: See also: [Query to get questions I voted on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51931/21960)

Comment: See also: [Electorate, Pundit, etc badge progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34432/21960)

Comment: Okay, this is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51931/query-to-get-questions-i-voted-on.  Thanks for the link; I had searched for something like that and not found it.  I have submitted a feature request all the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went and wrote a quick little script to extract this information from the vote history data.

To count the number of upvotes and downvotes you've made on questions and answers on a particular Stack Exchange site, go to any page on the site, open your browser's JS console, and paste and run the following code there:

```js
( function () {
    var uid = StackExchange.options.user.userId, site = StackExchange.options.site.name;
    var qCount = {}, aCount = {}, page = 1;
    function inc (count, type) { count[type] = (count[type] || 0) + 1; }
    function formatCounts (count) {
        var types = Object.keys(count).sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) types[i] += ' ' + count[types[i]];
        return types.join(', ');
    }
    function fetchVotePage () {
        var url = '/ajax/users/tab/' + uid+ '?tab=votes&sort=all&page=' + page;
        console.log( 'Fetching ' + url + ' ...' );
        $.get( url, function (html) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString( html, 'text/html' );
            var rows = doc.querySelectorAll('table.history-table tr');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var voteType = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "");
                if ( rows[i].querySelector('a.question-hyperlink') ) inc( qCount, voteType );
                if ( rows[i].querySelector('a.answer-hyperlink') ) inc( aCount, voteType );
            }
            if (doc.querySelector('.pager a[rel=next]')) {
                page++;
                setTimeout( fetchVotePage, 500 );  // wait 0.5s between requests
            }
            else {
                console.log('Total votes by user ' + uid + ' on ' + site + ':');
                console.log('Questions: ' + formatCounts(qCount) );
                console.log('Answers: ' + formatCounts(aCount) );
            }
        } );
    }
    fetchVotePage();
} )();
```

You should see a bunch of lines like `Fetching /ajax/users/tab/.../?tab=votes&sort=all&page=...` scrolling by on the console, as the script loads your voting history page by page.  Once it's done, it will print a summary of all your votes, e.g. like this:

```
Fetching /ajax/users/tab/411022?tab=votes&sort=all&page=179 ...
Fetching /ajax/users/tab/411022?tab=votes&sort=all&page=180 ...
Fetching /ajax/users/tab/411022?tab=votes&sort=all&page=181 ...
Total votes by user 411022 on Stack Overflow:
Questions: closure 764, deletion 113, downvote 111, reopen 82, undeletion 6, upvote 1550
Answers: deletion 132, downvote 130, undeletion 7, upvote 2524
```

As you can see from the sample output, the script also counts other types of votes shown on the vote history page, including close, reopen and delete votes.  Since I decided to use the "all" filter mode to get upvotes and downvotes in the same list, I decided that I might as well count the other types of votes as well.  In practice, they generally make up a rather small fraction of the total votes anyway.

BTW, it seems that the counts returned by this code *will not include up/down votes on deleted posts*, simply because those votes do not appear on the profile page vote list that it traverses.  I've confirmed this by finding a deleted answer on SO that I had both downvoted and del-voted, but for which only the deletion vote shows up on the list.  Close, reopen, delete and undelete vote counts do seem to include deleted posts *if* you have enough rep to see them.

Obviously, this script is not something you probably should run too frequently, since it sends a lot of Ajax requests to the SE servers.  On the other hand, at least the requests are sent serially, so that the script automatically slows itself down if the SE servers are slow to respond for any reason.  Also, I've added an extra 0.5 second delay between the requests to further reduce the risk of hitting any request rate limits.

p.s., While testing this, I noticed that the Firefox JS console doesn't seem to show any console output from asynchronous code until the user actually executes a console command.  This seems like a bug in the Firefox console to me.  If you're on Firefox and don't see any output after running this script, try typing something (e.g. `0`) into the console and pressing enter.  Keep repeating until the script is done and you see the final output.  Chrome seems to have no such issues.

If the script is taking too long and you want to abort it, the easiest way is to just reload the page.

Comment: Agreed. This script is neat, as long as you're not a user with high activity on the site in question as SE will throttle your requests.

Comment: @Werner you might want to change the `0` in this line `setTimeout( fetchVotePage, 0 );` to something higher, 1000 is safe but 500 could work.

Comment: @rene: The point of the `setTimeout()` is just to avoid recursion limits. (Actually, it's probably unnecessary, since `$.get()` should unwind the call stack anyway.) I guess putting an actual small delay there coudn't hurt much, and would set a hard limit on the Ajax request rate. But in any case, the code won't fire another request before the previous one has completed, so the only situation where a delay would really make a difference is, paradoxically, if the SE servers are handling the requests really fast and efficiently.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen but I do recall that the HA-Proxy keeps count on the number of request you make per 90 seconds. You get throttled by the proxy. You need to take that into account.

Comment: @rene: Fair enough, I've added a 0.5 second delay between requests into the code, just in case. I have not actually been able to trigger any kind of rate limits even without it, but it's probably still better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Votes' tab in your profile which shows all your votes, and sub-tabs for downvotes and upvotes, but it is hard to see which ones are for questions and which for answers. You need to examine each link to do that - with a lot of votes, that's undoable.

Because downvotes on *answers* cost reputation (and on questions they don't), there's an easy way to find them: visit the reputation text page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and let the Find dialog of the browser tell you how many times the term `(-1)` appears. This doesn't include downvotes on deleted answers though, so you can't subtract it from the vote totals on your profile, which do include votes on deleted posts.

Comment: This still doesn't split questions and answers, which *was my question*.

Comment: @anonymous2 it is a *partial* answer - you'll get the number of downvotes on answers.

Answer (score 1):

That data is not currently available. It's not exposed via the user interface, and individual votes are not accessible in the SEDE. (The upvotes and downvotes on the `User` table are just counts. They're not broken out by post type.)

You should probably create a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask that it be added.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Now we're getting somewhere... ;)