# See count of votes on questions vs. answers

Tags: feature-request, voting, statistics

I recently asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285684/determine-number-of-votes-on-questions/285686?noredirect=1#285686) to determine whether it is possible to get a count of the number of my upvotes that are on questions vs. answers (or at least a percentage).

I am proposing that under the vote tabs `all`, `upvote`, `downvote`, etc, there be another list of tabs that would split the votes between questions and answers.

Comment: There already is? Bottom of the Activity page...

Comment: @Catija Ok, it's not *quite* what I was looking for: it doesn't split up down and up.

Comment: Ah. Hmmm. It's a start, at least :P