# List all posts that I upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow

I could not see any way to list all posts I upvoted.

Profile page only shows the counts for upvotes & downvotes.

It would be good if there was a way to list all posts for which we have used upvotes/downvotes. It would help us rectify if we made any mistakes, and I think it would be useful to refer to all the posts I have upvoted (as upvoting mostly implies its a useful post and more likely that I may need to refer to it later).

Comment: Since these things never die on the internet, it is possible someone will come here from a search, as I did.  The situation has now changed, see my comment below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This functionality (view your vote history) used to be available from your user profile page, under a tab labeled "votes", but was removed when the "recent" pages were added.  Granted, the recent page shows a great deal of other useful information that was previously not easily available, but it's no longer an easy thing to simply see your own voting activity.

The open feature request to restore this functionality is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go).

Comment: I don't know when it became available again, but it is available now.  It's the last item in the horizontal menu in your profile.

Comment: Since the votes tab is back (since 2012), this answer is outdated. See answer by @Hemanth: "Go to your Profile page -> Click Users Tab -> Click Activity Tab -> Click Votes Tab".

Answer (score 4):

I can see that it is old question but above answers didn't help me as I was unable to find what I am looking for. So, I am writing this answer to those who are searching for posts they have upvoted like I did just now.

Go to your Profile page -> Click Users Tab -> Click Activity Tab -> Click Votes Tab

Answer (score 0):

When ever you vote, you can click the star which is right under neath of the up and down votes. This will favorite the question. You can then check your profile and click on the favorites tab to come back to those questions.

Comment: What you are suggesting only seems to apply to questions, and not to answers.  There is no favorite star under the up and down votes for answers.