# View my upvotes

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the Votes Tab go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go)
>   [List all posts that I upvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32458/list-all-posts-that-i-upvoted)

When I go to a question I've previously voted on, the questions and answers that I voted for indicate as such; if I try to vote again, I'm refused.  Obviously this information exists, so is there a way of collectively viewing the questions and answers that I have previously voted on?  If not, I think one is merited.

I only ask because on more than one occasion, I casually vote for something without thinking to favorite it, and some days or weeks later I come across a related problem or topic - but when I go to try and dig up that vote I placed, I come up dry.

Comment: No idea how my search missed those.  Close away.

Comment: Ironically the dupe got 2K views while the original got 1K