# Can I see my vote history?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, bookmarks, recent-activity

I know I can see my total count of votes, but I'd be interested in having these be part of my activity tab, so I can easily revisit questions. I end up favoriting almost every question I upvote, just so I have a way to go back to it.

Comment: @Rathony: Why are you flagging a completed feature request from six years ago as a dupe of a support question from today? That could not possibly be more backwards.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The answer in the dupe master has more helpful content for current and future users than the answer below.

Comment: @Rathony: That doesn't make a lot of sense. It's a *feature request*. The only "helpful content" needed is to know why it was or wasn't implemented, or possibly a useful workaround if it isn't.

Comment: @NathanTuggy 5 users seem to agree with my flag. If you have an issue with this, you can post a question here.

Comment: @Rathony well, I disagree with the flag. Reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well done. Let's move on.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is available in the form of a "votes" tab in your user profile.

(It was removed for some reason at some point [but it's back now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go).)

Comment: i wish i could view all my votes for all the sites on one page