# Find questions that I have upvoted

Tags: feature-request, voting, bookmarks

Is there a way to search/list the questions that I have upvoted?

Sometimes I will upvote a good question for which I wish to return later and view the answers.

I realized that I could "favorite" the question, but I feel there is a difference between what I am describing and a "favorite" question.

If this does not exist, I think there should be a tab under my profile to show recent questions that ive upvoted(or otherwise marked to be of interest to me)

Comment: Yes it probably would fit in the Activities tab. It may even warrant its own tab to avoid getting lost in the noise of other activities.

Comment: There may also be some value in showing "recently viewed" questions in general to view recent answers/comments even if you had not participated in that particular question.

Answer (score 19):

You can now view votes in your profile view on the far right under the votes tab.

[image: Votes Tab]

**See also**:

- [Can I see my vote history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41932/209031)
- [Where did the Votes Tab go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14610/209031)