# Can I see my own "close vote history"?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Yesterday, I voted to close a question as a duplicate. Today, I'm curious if the question is still open, but I did not keep a link to that question.

Is there some way to see a list or history of questions that I voted to close? On my activity tab, I can only find "reviews", which does not include questions that I vote on outside of reviews.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I see my vote history?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/can-i-see-my-vote-history)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can. On the Activity tab, there is a Votes tab (it's the rightmost tab). One of the sub-tabs is 'Closure', that's the tab you're looking for. You will only see non-deleted questions, unless you happen to have more than 10k reputation.

[image: activity tab -> votes -> closure]

The direct link to your close votes is https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure; other users won't be able to see this overview.