# Keep track of where I have upvoted/downvoted

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes, tracking

I'd like to see the list of questions and answers where I have left a upvote/downvote. I also would like to see a list of comments that I have upvoted.

Today I only have the count of upvotes/downvotes but no tracking available.

Right know I'm trying to remember where I left a upvote for a really interesting comment. I'd like to copy/mention a phrase of that comment to a blog post I'm writing.

For example: if I click one of my tags, I'm presented with a list of questions I've answered that were tagged with that specific tag. This is the kind of functionality that would help me track my upvotes/downvotes.

I tried Google but couldn't get to the question that contain that specific comment I'm looking for.

---

**Edit:** I just found the phrase using Google. This is the query I used:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=you+think+you+know+everything+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

This is the phrase:

> There's a saying: When you finish your
>   bachelor's, you think you know
>   everything; When you finish your
>   master's, you realize you know
>   nothing; When you finish your
>   doctorate, you realize nobody knows
>   anything, including whether or not you
>   needed to finish a doctorate to
>   realize that.

Note: I didn't find the comment I upvoted but just found an answer that has the same phrase.

Comment: There used to be a "Votes" tab that had that information.  They removed it though...not sure why.

Comment: When was that? Didn't see that.

Comment: [Where did the Votes Tab go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go)

Comment: It was removed about 11 months ago I guess.  It just kept track of your most recent ~30 up and down votes.

Comment: Although not seeing the "Votes" tab before I miss it right now. :)

Comment: SEDE is back up, but you can't write a query that shows all the upvotes and downvotes for a given user; that would be a bit of an anonymity fail :)

Comment: @Michael, yeah, the Votes tab was only for you to see. Other people couldn't see your votes tab.

Comment: @Justin Yeah, I was referring to the OP's first revision where he said "I thought about writing a query at http://odata.stackexchange.com/ to fetch the data if this is possible (at least I think it is)"; hopefully that isn't possible :)

Comment: This has actually been completed (the votes tab is back), but does not show your comment votes.  It only shows votes on questions / answers.

Comment: [The votes tab is there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/155556)