# Is there a way I can see the comments I've upvoted?

Tags: support, comments, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep track of where I have upvoted/downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58525/keep-track-of-where-i-have-upvoted-downvoted)

I know I can see my vote history on questions and answers, and I've seen other questions about retrieving data for votes on comments that I've left, but is there a way to get a list of other people's comments that I've upvoted?

Comment: "I also would like to see a list of comments that I have upvoted." on the other question from two years ago @lix

Comment: So based on the comments on the question that this question was closed as a dupe of, the answer is that there's no way?

Comment: @random It seems like this is really (in essence) a feature-request to add a "comments" filter to the votes tab (although I agree it's similar to the older question).  j08691 - if that's the case, please edit your question accordingly (add the feature-request tag, etc)

Comment: Note the question that this is marked a duplicate of is also a duplicate itself.  Should this be fixed?