# Add a way I can see the comments I've upvoted

Tags: feature-request, comments, voting, activity

I know that this question has been asked multiple times like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141672/is-there-a-way-i-can-see-the-comments-ive-upvoted) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58525/keep-track-of-where-i-have-upvoted-downvoted). But as you can see, by visiting the links, most of the times the question has been closed without any resolution. Hence, I'm asking this again to request a way to see the comments (not questions/answers) I've upvoted throughout history.

As shown in this picture, I'm aware that you can check the questions/answers you have upvoted/downvoted:

[image: question and answer upvote and downvote history]

But I want to see the *comments* I have upvoted as well. In case my point isn't being understood well, here's what I mean by upvotes of comments:

[image: upvote of comment]

Comment: No, you can't. Follow or Save the post instead.

Comment: @rene I thought so. In that case, I guess this question should be considered as a feature request.

Comment: I guess SE wouldn't work on this since comments are supposed to temporary and generally meant for clarifying doubts about the question. But, I could be wrong I guess.

Comment: Bear in mind that comments are designed to be ephemeral and you should expect them to be deleted. So this isn't really something that is likely to happen, the feature goes against the point of comments.

Comment: @terdon still it'd be nice to see a complete log of your activity on the StackExchange communities. And if the comments are meant to be deleted eventually, so be it. Just make sure the deletion's also included in the activity log.