# See what you have voted on

Tags: feature-request, voting

I have given 9 up votes, but as far as I can see there's no way of seeing what I voted on. Should that be added?

The reason I'm wondering is because I read a really good answer to a question the other week, and although I voted up the answer (not the accepted if I remember correctly) I stupidly, stupidly did not mark it as a favourite. Now I want to see what other answers that particular user has given, but have no way of finding it again.

I can't remember the username or the exact question, and as this user was very good at describing how to read code I want to read more of what he's written, and it drives me mad that I can't find it!

Comment: Check your browser's history?

Comment: Unfortunately I've had to delete my history! Oh well, I will continue to search. If I remember correctly it was Jon Skeet's answer that was accepted, this user's answer was the one with the second most votes. I think the username started with Ha, but I'm not sure, and one of the comments for the answer said '+1 for explaning how to read code' or something similar. So I've probably got, oh I don't know, about a million more questions to look through. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of April 26, 2012 the [votes tab in our profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) [is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go/130380#130380):

> [image]

In there, you can easily see what you've voted on.

Comment: Yes, showing all votes might be overkill but showing the most recent ones sounds like a great idea, shame it was removed!

Comment: The votes tab [came back 3.5 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/152859) - want to edit your answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uhm ... yes. Thanks.

Comment: Not what I had in mind. Edited it myself now, if you want feel free to roll back and I'll post it as new answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here is an answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63250/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-many-of-my-votes-went-to-jon-skeet/63263#63263) that explains why you actually cannot figure out which answers you have up voted (easily, that is).... basically because they carry no reputation increase or decrease.

On the other hand you can track your down votes using your [**reputation audit**](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), since down votes do carry a reputation decrease.