# Show all the posts I voted up in my user account details

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, up-votes

It would be nice to see all the questions or answers I have voted up, as upvotes indicate that I like the answer or the question and might like to revisit it at some point later.

Answer (score 6):

As of April 26 (2012) each user has a [votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130380/152859) in his own profile, visible only to him of course.

This allows you to filter your votes, e.g. see only your upvotes, downvotes etc and for each vote a link to the relevant post. (Note: it won't show deleted posts)

Comment: It should be `status-completed` instead of `status-declined`.

Comment: Yep, I just flagged the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is why you favorite questions. You click the star under the questions up down vote count and it will appear in your favorites tab in your profile. And you can view that question again whenever you want it will always be under your favorites tab.

Comment: yes, but then one would not want to favorite each question he votes up

Comment: @keshav, why not? I certainly don't favorite every question I upvote, but favorites exist so you can mark questions you like and may want to revisit, which is exactly the use case you're describing.

Comment: @popular demand:: i vote up whenever i read some questions and answers and if i like the answer or get to know something new or interesting, this does not mean its my favorite. favorites is usually a much shorter list than the vote ups.

Comment: @keshav, I think you're taking the name "favorite" too literally. The feature has almost always been used as more of a bookmark than an actual list of favorite questions; this behavior was recognized when favorite notifications were implemented. If you want to keep using it your way, that's fine, but there are so many upvotes thrown around on a daily basis that, for most people, a list of all upvoted posts would be so large as to be useless.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have this feature (prior to adding favorites) and removed it due to utter lack of utility once favorites were implemented.

Doubful that it will come back.

Comment: Just because I vote something up doesn't make it a favorite of mine.  If I marked everything I voted up as a favorite, it would negate the usefulness of being able to track an actual favorite.

Comment: This would become a pretty long list.. Press the star instead!

Comment: -1 The favorite system doesn't replace the ability to see the posts you up- and down-voted.

Comment: I agree with Erik B