# Search among posts you've voted for

Tags: feature-request, search, voting

> **Related posts:**
>
> [Possible to search questions I voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48830/possible-to-search-questions-i-voted-on)
>
> [Show all the posts I voted up in my user account details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/show-all-the-posts-i-voted-up-in-my-user-account-details)

*These posts are different from mine in that they merely ask for the "votes" tab back or ask if it is at all possible to get such information, while I propose how to implement this as a search feature.*

## Background

I recently found myself facing a problem very similar to one that I had solved before. I remembered that I found the solution on SO and I remembered upvoting the post containing the solution.

I wasn't able to find that particular post by just searching with relevant keywords. It would have been nice if I could search only among the questions I have voted on.

I searched on meta and found that there had been a tab for looking at what you've voted on, but that it was removed due to lack of interest. This is understandable, since just listing the hundreds/thousands of posts you've voted on isn't particularly useful.

## Proposal

What I want is to be able to search for posts I've voted on similarly to the way I'm able to search on my posts within a specific tag.

For instance:

```
user:310121 [iphone] apple
```

This will return all my posts tagged iPhone, where I mention Apple. This is brilliant. This is just how I want search to work. Now what I want to do is to extend this to include votes.

The exact syntax isn't relevant, but I had to make one up to show you what I mean:

**To show all posts you've voted on:**

```
user:310121 {votes}
```

**To show all posts you've upvoted:**

```
user:310121 {upvotes}
```

**To show all posts you've downvoted:**

```
user:310121 {downvotes}
```

You could probably omit the the user part, since you're only allowed to see your own votes. (Unless it's desirable to be able to look at other peoples votes. Maybe you should be allowed to do this if you have enough rep? Well, that's another discussion.) I guess that even if you're allowed to see other peoples votes it would make sense to display your own votes if the user part is omitted.

So in my case I could have done the following search and found the post I was looking for:

```
{upvotes} keyword
```

Lastly I just want to suggest that clicking on your vote count will work just like clicking on a tag. If I click on a tag in my profile the following search will be done:

```
user:310121 [tag]
```

So if I click on my upvote count the following search should be made:

```
user:310121 {upvotes}
```

The same goes for downvotes:

```
user:310121 {downvotes}
```

***This would be a very useful feature and it wouldn't be intrusive in any way. The users that don't care for this feature might never know that it's there. And just for the record the favorite system doesn't replace this feature.***

Comment: *Please hear me out before closing this as a duplicate or declining the request. This is different from what's been suggested before.*:  can you link to these previous requests and explain how this is different from those proposals?

Comment: I always wanted to find out the only one my downvoted question on Stack Overflow, this would be good idea for that purpose.

Comment: @Rebecca Related posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48830/possible-to-search-questions-i-voted-on and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/show-all-the-posts-i-voted-up-in-my-user-account-details

Comment: @Rebecca They mainly just ask for that tab back or if there is one.

Comment: You should edit that into your post instead of begging people at the top of your post. (;

Comment: @Rebecca, yeah probably, I just thought that maybe someone would feel like they'd already declined this feature request without realizing that this one was different. Thus closing this one as a duplicate or declining it.

Comment: If you want your post to be considered as different from previous posts, I think it is fair to say that it is on you to be show you've read previous posts and explain why it is different.  That information belongs in the post.

Comment: @Rebecca I updated the post to include "that information". Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: This was never implemented, right? Would be good.

Comment: Would have loved this too - trying to look up something I've seen a year or two ago, and right now am not getting results to the same posts ...