# Personal voting history review page

Tags: feature-request, voting, profile-page

This thought just occurred to me today:

> I'd really like a way to see all the posts I've down-voted, so that I can check to see if there's been any changes made that warrant removal of the down-vote.

Would it be possible to add a feature that allows us to review posts based on our voting history?  This could be implemented as a click-able link (that works for *you only*) on your profile page, where the current up/down-vote counts are.

Comment: Doesn't this already show up under the `Reputation` tab in your activity, or do you mean something else? It doesn't show questions you voted up, I suppose.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Yes, when filtered by post; maybe it would be worth having a filter on the types of entries shown.

Comment: @edlarerathis - It does, along with every single other rep-earning or rep-reducing event that's ever occurred.  It would be much more concise, and better serving of the purpose, to view a page that *only* has your voting history.

Comment: +1 I was just about to ask about this myself. I also would like such a history, not seldom I want to go back not only to my down votes but also to the upvotes, to see if anyone else has posted good answers. I know I could do this using favorites, but these I would like to keep as just that - favorites - and to keep them in a longer perspective.

Comment: May I know where is the link to see who upvote or downvote my questions? I try to be a good user on SO but sometimes people downvote without leaving reasons makes it difficult to know my mistakes. The converse applies for upvotes.

Comment: @Jake - What prompted this question was the fact that we can't even review *our own* voting history.  What makes you think, under those circumstances, that we'd be able to view the voting history of *others*?

Answer (score 4):

In the beginning...

There was a votes page in the profile, but then the Powers That Be decided that it wasn't useful and they got rid of it.  While I never used it much personally, quite a few others lamented its demise.

[More Detail Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go).

Answer (score 2):

In the event that this feature is not implemented on Stack Overflow proper, I have tentatively made a request for a `/me/votes` route in the [Draft Specification for API v2.0](https://stackapps.com/q/2588/8284). If this is ever added to the API, app developers could implement a feature to allow a user to view *his or her own* voting history. Note that this would *not* make any user's voting history public to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This feature now exists.

You can access it via visiting your own activity page (by clicking on the your avatar/reputation/badge count in the top bar), then clicking on "votes" and "downvote".

The resulting URL will look something like this:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/*userid*/*username*?tab=votes&sort=downvote

Note that you can only do this for yourself, while logged in; it won't show you another user's votes.