# Viewing past votes

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Personal voting history review page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89989/personal-voting-history-review-page)

I found a great answer to a question that had already been posted by another. I voted up the question and the answer. Now I would like to find that question/answer. I don't seem to be able to recreate original query. Is there a way to view my own past votes?

Comment: Was it today?  How about your browser history?