# "View more" Votes profile button link broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Whilst viewing someone else's profile, click on "view more" underneath Votes, you'll get a **Page Not Found** error.

**NOTE: It works when you do it on your own profile**

Try it on my StackOverflow profile [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo).  When logged in as someone else and viewing my profile,

> [image]

Scroll to the bottom for the 'votes' section.  This section incorrectly shows a 'view more' link which should be private:

> [image]

Clicking this link will bring you to `/users/1039608/mattytommo?tab=votes`, which is not viewable if you're not the listed user (as it should be).

> [image]

The 'view more' link should not be shown.

Comment: It not supposed to work on other users' profile. The bug is that there's a link.

Comment: On a related note: When did we get a votes tab?

Comment: @Dennis Yeah I thought that originally

Comment: @Dennis It must be new actually, I thought that the other day

Comment: @Dennis That was [implemented last month](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go), so you guys are correct - it *is* new!

Comment: @jadarnel27: Nice! I've always wanted a votes tab, but I probably wouldn't have found if it wasn't for this bug...

Comment: Also reported here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1169/472

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "view more" link will no longer be shown if you're not viewing your own profile.

A fix will be pushed in the next build, after rev 2012.6.6.2794.

Comment: it's still there

Comment: Someone checked in some bad code that caused the "view more" to be displayed - they were given a stern talking to :) A fix will be pushed out in the next build, after rev 2012.8.15.3676.